# {$IFOPT A4}?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

In Delphi 2009 (or older versions), how do you check the "Align" compile option in the code?

The `IFOPT` directive seems to work only with pure switches ( `{$IFOPT A4}` does not compile ).

I couldn't find an equivalent constant or such defined ( `{$IF Align = 4}` or such )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by defining a record with known packing rules and check it using SizeOf.  Tested in Delphi 2009:

```
type
  TTestRec = record
    A: Byte;
    B: Int64;
  end;

{$IF SIZEOF(TTestRec) = 9}
  {$MESSAGE HINT '$A1'}
{$ELSEIF SIZEOF(TTestRec) = 10}
  {$MESSAGE HINT '$A2'}
{$ELSEIF SIZEOF(TTestRec) = 12}
  {$MESSAGE HINT '$A4'}
{$ELSEIF SIZEOF(TTestRec) = 16}
  {$MESSAGE HINT '$A8'}
{$ELSE}
  {$MESSAGE HINT 'Unknown alignment'}
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Do we have a rock-solid guaranty that the compiler treats in the exact same way non packed records and local variables placed on the stack? (I certainly do hope so, but I have had several surprises when testing the compiler behaviour on other features...)

Answer (score 2):

Write code to test the actual runtime behavior. Only way I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

There is {$IFOPT A+} directive, but it doesn't tell you alignment value.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is no way to do this :(

Comment: I agree. I don't know of any way to do this either. (Not sure why you'd need to; I can't think of any reason you'd need to know this at compile time, or what you'd do differently in code if you *did* know.

Comment: Certain tasks only work on properly-aligned values. A lot of SIMD instructions are like that, for example...

Comment: @Mason: That's right, but why not simply *demand* or force proper alignment, and do the same thing the processor does when misaligning, i.e. throw?

Comment: Trying to implement allen bauer's idea to create generic multicast events, we found several bugs, among others in ObjAuto.pas.

For example, his solution implies creating at runtime a TMethodPointer from a method (and its TypeInfo), using ObjAuto.CreateMethodPointer.

This function incorrectly assumes (through nested calls : line 726) that local variables and arguments are not aligned on the stack. To fix this, for example, we need to know the alignment size.

Allen Bauer's original post : http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/08/15/38865#comment-11698

Comment: I'm using smart records to generate 4-aligned and 8-aligned values. See TGp4AlignedInt and TGp8AlignedInt64 in my GpStuff unit (most recent version is at http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/GpStuff.pas).