# Delphi forms.pas memory leak?

Tags: delphi, memory, dll, memory-leaks

HI

I have a dynamic link library writting in Delphi 2006 that has forms.pas in its uses clause.

If I load the dll and then immediately unload it in a for loop, say 10000 times, the memory slowly climbs.  However if I take Forms.pas out of the uses clause of the dll then the problem goes away.

The code is very simple

Here is my code for the dll:

```
library Project1;

uses
  Forms;

begin

end.
```

Here is my code for the calling application:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t_ImportHandle: LongInt;
  t_Index: Integer;
begin
  for t_Index := 0 to 10000 - 1 do
  begin
    t_ImportHandle := LoadLibrary('Project1.dll');
    FreeLibrary(t_ImportHandle);
  end;
 end;
```

Is anyone else able to replicate this or know what the cause is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TApplication.Create` uses the `MakeObjectInstance` function in Classes.pas.  MakeObjectInstance allocates a 4KB buffer using VirtualAlloc, but doesn't free it, so each time you load/unload the DLL it's going to leak that much.  Andreas Hausladen used to have a blog post about it, but it looks like he's taken it down.  There's a fix posted on [CodeCentral](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25104), and it's also included as part of Andreas's [VCL Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/vclfixpack-10/) package.

Comment: I also believe this specific issue is fixed as of Delphi 2010.

Comment: Thanks for that, the patch has indeed fixed the problem.  Im wondering instead of using the patch can i just edit the VCL (as I have done this to fix other bugs) and free Block before leaving MakeObjectInstance?  i've looked at the code but it assigns pointers to different variables so I can't work out if its safe to free block at the end of the function or not.

Comment: @Craig: do you know if this ever ended up in QC?

Comment: Looks like it made it into QC as 3507, but was closed as "As Designed".  As Ken says though, there is code to cleanup the blocks in the later Delphi releases, so they must have fixed it at some point.

Comment: @no spoon: Take a look at QC#3507.  It has a workaround that frees the code in the finalization section.  The Delphi 2010 version does the same thing.  It's definitely not safe to free it in MakeObjectInstance, and based on the fixes it's probably not safe to do it in FreeObjectInstance either.

Comment: I noticed that in the MkObjInstLeakFix it has some compiler switches defined, most concerning is $A+ which controls recond alignment.  Also $D+, $L+ and $Y+ which controls debug info, local symbols and reference info. In our .cfg files for the projects we turn off D, L and Y, are they required in order for this patch to work or is it safe to turn them off in the patch unit? or because they are turned on in the patch unit, does this mean they only apply to this unit?

Comment: Also A+ is most concerning because we use record alignment of 0 for our data structures, anything else will cause corruption.  Using A+ in the patch unit sets the record alignment to 8, will this affect the whole project or only the patch unit?  Do the compiler switches defined in our project cfg file override the switches set in the patch unit?

Comment: The compiler switches defined in the patch unit, can I just turn then off at the end of the unit?  I'm just very concerned about that impact they may have on the rest of the project.

Comment: AFAIK, compiler switches only control the file they're in (excluding files included using $I), so it shouldn't affect the rest of your project.  You can use $IFOPT to verify that;  here's how to do  {$IFOPT A#}: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829235/.  I tested it myself with a simple project and that's how it worked.

Comment: OK thanks for that, yeah it turns out that those switches only apply to the patch unit.

Comment: As an alternative to adding the fix unit into the dll code. Is there a way to free the memory consumed by a dll externally? i.e. can you schedule an application that cleans up the memory consumed but not freed when a dll is unloaded?  a bit like a garbage collector?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a leak but a memory manager fragmentation issues.

Why don't try using FastMM advanced logging and see if there is a leak indeed.

Comment: I've tried using FastMM in both the DLL and the calling application but the problem still continues and fastmm does not report a memory leak, in fact it doesn't report anything.  I created a memory leak in the calling application and fastmm will report that but if i put i memeory leak into the dll, fastmm doesn't report it, maybe i've set it up wrong?

Comment: Anyway according to this post https://forums.codegear.com/messageview.jspa?messageID=296979 this is a know issue but I can't get access to the link http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=20712 even though I have a valid login.

Comment: Alright i've traced the problem down to something to do with creating the application object in Controls.pas.  In the initialisation section of controls.pas there is a call to InitControls.  In this method the global Application object is initialized to an instance of TApplication.  If I comment out this line and the Application.ShowHint := true line then the problem goes away.  However creating and freeing instances of the TApplication object in a loop does not cause a memory leak.